# Как закрыть SerialPort, если клиент закрывает Soket

Tags: java, сокет, потоки-данных

Ситуация вот какая: клиент и сервер общаются через сокет. Сервер с модемом через `SerialPort`. И сокет и сериал-Порт имеют свои `Input-` и `OutputStream`. На сервере я читаю из сокетного `InputStream` и засовываю это в `OutputStream` сериал-Порта.
Когда клиент у себя делает `socket.close()`, как серверу в ответ на это закрыть `SerialPort`?
Спасибо.

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import gnu.io.*;

public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {
    private SerialPort port = null;
    private Socket client;
    private InputStream serialPortInputStream;
    private OutputStream serialPortOutputStream;
    private InputStream clientInputStream;
    private OutputStream clientOutputStream;
    private boolean isStopWork = false;

    public ClientConnection(Socket client) {
        this.client = client; 
    }

    public void run() {        
        try {
            port = ModemManager.getFreePort();
        }
        catch (PortInUseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            clientInputStream = client.getInputStream();
            clientOutputStream = client.getOutputStream();
            serialPortInputStream = port.getInputStream();
            serialPortOutputStream = port.getOutputStream();

            byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[512];
            byte[] serialPortBuffer = new byte[512];
            int readFromSerial;
            int readFromClient;

            readFromClient = clientInputStream.read(clientBuffer);
            serialPortOutputStream.write(clientBuffer, 0, readFromClient);
            while ((readFromSerial = serialPortInputStream.read(serialPortBuffer)) != -1) {
                try {
                    readFromClient = clientInputStream.read(clientBuffer);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    port.close();
                }
                clientOutputStream.write(serialPortBuffer, 0, readFromSerial);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                clientInputStream.close();
                clientOutputStream.close();
                serialPortInputStream.close();
                serialPortOutputStream.close();
                port.close();
                client.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int rc;

    while ((rc = fromClientIS.read(buffer)) != -1)
        modemOS.write(buffer, 0, rc);
} finally {
    modemOS.close();
    fromClientIS.close();
}
```

Comment: У меня немного другая ситуация. Я в цикле читаю из модема, а не из клиента.

Comment: Ну так читайте оба направления. Когда случится обрыв, закрывайте всё. Правда придётся ковыряться с потоками.

Comment: А как читать в оба направления одновременно? я не могу понять((

Comment: У меня эта работа итак идёт в Thread. Мне что ещё 2 создавать? Один чтоб занимался? чтением сокет->модем, а другой модем->сокет?

Comment: Зачем два? Один надо ещё сделать. А как иначе узнать, что какой-то сокет закрыт, если мы заблокировании на чтении другого? Вариантов просто напросто нет.